# How do I make a "View All" button display data via segue to the next ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UIButton`(View All) found inside a `UITableViewCell` in which a `UICollectionView` is embedded. When the `UIButton` is pressed, it should pass & list all the items found in the `UICollectionView` to the destination `ViewController`.

Here is the code for my `UITableViewCell` containing the `UIButton` & `UICollectionView`:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var ViewAllButton: UIButton!

 @IBOutlet weak var EventCollection: UICollectionView!

 var events = [Events]()

 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
  ViewAllButton.setIcon(prefixText: "View All ", prefixTextColor: .blue, icon: .typIcons(.chevronRight), iconColor: .blue, postfixText: " ", forState: .normal, iconSize: 24)
 }

 extension PopularCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return events.count
   }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = EventCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell
            let event = events[indexPath.row]
            print("Event Name:\(event.event_name)")
             cell.event = event
         cell.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell

    }
```

How do I go along to make the `UIButton`(View All) display the items found in the `UICollectionView` at a particular index to the destination `ViewController` ?

Comment: How do you determine your index? If it's set somewhere in your view/view controller then every time you set your index you could retrieve data from your dataSource and if the view all button is pressed then you can pass it to the next VC via prepareForSegue

Comment: Very unclear question. Reframe your question so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. Add the following code with in a new file named UIView_Ext:

    extension UIView {
        var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
            var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
            while parentResponder != nil {
                parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
                if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                    return viewController
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

2. On View All button Action in the tableViewCell do the following:

    self.parentViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue_Identifer", sender: self.events)

3. Implement prepare for segue in the view controller you are having table view controller reference as below:

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "Segue_Identifier" {
                let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! DestinationViewController
                destinationViewController.events = events
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the UIView_Ext file, I am getting these errors: `use of undeclared type UIView` , `use of undeclared type UIViewController` & `use of undeclared type UIResponder`

Comment: import UIKit in that

Comment: Ok your solution works, but it shows me all the events. I want to see events for a particular table row which are classified into categories per index row

Comment: You have to send the index to the table view cell and make a variable with indexPath into it  and assign that index (sending from tableView cellForRowAt indexPath) to variable in cell and when ViewAll is Clicked. Fetch item at that particular index from the larger array.